# Capture ExecuteNonQuery Event

Tags: c#, .net

Can I capture an "ExecuteNonQuery" event? For instance, in the code below, I want to capture ExecuteNonQuery command:

```
private void test()
{
myConnection.Open();
        sql = "Create Database DatabaseName";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,myConnection);
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //CAPTURE THIS, send sql variable
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        //Do Something here
        }
}
private void capturedExecuteNonQuery(sql)
{
MessageBox.Show("You captured it!" + sql);
}
```

Any suggestions to accomplishing this appreciated!

Comment: I dont want to capture that value. When I put ExecuteNonQuery in code, I want to capture the variable SQL. I'll write that to an audit log of sorts to see all of the sql commands that were run.

Comment: You're not being clear. Do you want to log the sql variable when ExecuteNonQuery is successful? If not, I have no idea what you are asking for. Can you use another word besides "capture" to describe what you're trying to accomplish?